# ggplot `scale_fill_manual()` alternate colors infinitely

Tags: r, ggplot2

My *first code chunk* works fine, although my throwaway value of `999` is the opposite of elegant. I'm trying to get the first bar red, then alternate blue and green. Probably not the best way to alternate my blue and green colors but it works.

```
# FIRST CODE CHUNK
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg, aes(fl)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = fl)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("red", rep(c("blue", "green"), 999))
  )
```

I wanted to `scale_fill_manual()` and just recycle the blue and green infinitely but that doesn't work. I get the "5 needed only 3 provided" error.

```
# SECOND CODE CHUNK
ggplot(mpg, aes(fl)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = fl)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(red, c("blue", "green"))
  )
```

How can I recycle the blue and green colors in my `scale_fill_manual()` command? I imagine it'd be something like

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c(red, rep(c("blue", "green"), recycle.infinite)))
```

Comment: Is your question pedagogical or practical? I'm not sure how you would actually recycle it infinitely, but you could just use two `geom_bar` calls one where the data is only for that bar and one where the data is for the rest of the set . . .

Comment: good questions, so in the first chunk, see how I just recycle blue/green manually `999` times? What's the better way to do that? Even with your suggestions, how would I alternate blue/green for the second geom set, would it still need to be manual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
scale_fill_manual(
     values = c("red", rep_len(c("blue", "green"), length(unique(mpg$fl))-1))
```

Comment: Why do you use `rep_len()` instead of the simpler `rep()`? Both seem to work the same.

Comment: both work, because `scale_fill_manual` doesn't care how many values you have beyond what it needs (which is why 999 worked). But for my arbitrarily defined elegance, I wanted to provide it with the exact number of values it needed, hence `rep_len`. `rep` would give you twice the number of values you need, strictly speaking. (if you don't care about that, you can also drop the `-1`.

Comment: but `rep_len(1, 5)` and `rep(1, 5)` are both the same length. One is not twice the length of the other. Are you sure? (Of course you are, just asking as figure of speech)

Comment: That's because 1 is length 1. Try comparing `rep(c(1:2),5)` with `rep_len(c(1:2),5)` (or `rep(c(1:2),length.out=5)`).